# edit or change injected content from {{ content_for_header }}

Tags: shopify, facebook-pixel

There is a fb pixel still imbedded in the header of my shopify store. using the facebook pixel helper it says I still have a fb pixel in my header. I looked into it and saw it is in my {{ content_for_header }}.

I have tried .remove() and | remove: and I still have the fb pixel in the header of my theme.liquid

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `replace` or `remove` filter on `content_for_header`

It's not recommended to modify the `content_for_header` but, I will show you how to modify it.

First, comment it

```
{%- comment -%}
  {{ content_for_header }}
{%- endcomment -%}
```

This will let you update the file with `theme watch`

Second, Use capture for custom `content_for_header`

```
{% capture custom_content_for_header %}
    {{ content_for_header | replace: 'your-text-to-be-replaced', 'new-text'
{% endcapture %}
```

Last, print your custom content for header

```
 {{ custom_content_for_header }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove or replace strings like below

Replace

```
{{ content_for_header | replace: 'string to be replaced', 'inserted' }}
```

To remove

```
{{ content_for_header | remove: '' }}
```

Otherwise you can't really edit `{{ content_for_header }}`

Comment: If you get an error saying that content_for_header does not exist.

Try this alternative:

`{% capture h_content %}
{{ content_for_header }}
{% endcapture %}

{% if h_content contains "string to be replaced" %}
{{ h_content | replace: 'inserted' }}
{% else %}
{{ content_for_header }}
{% endif %}`